# An inequality involving the Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is binomial $B(n,p)$ with $p > 0$ fixed and $a > 0 $, I want to show that

$$ P \bigg( \bigg| \frac{X}{n} - p \bigg| > a \bigg) \leq \frac{ \sqrt{p(1-p)} }{a^2n} \min \bigg\{ \sqrt{p(1-p)} , a \sqrt{n} \bigg\}$$

I was trying to write $P \bigg( \bigg| \frac{X}{n} - p \bigg| > a \bigg) = 1 - P\bigg( \bigg| \frac{X}{n} - p \bigg| \leq a \bigg) = 1 - P( n(p-a) \leq X \leq n(p+a) )$

And this equals to

$$ 1 - \sum_{k = n(p-a) }^{n(p+a)} { n \choose k }p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Here I am stuck since I cant seem to estimate it. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the two cases. If $a\sqrt n \ge\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, you're being asked to show:
$$
P \bigg( \bigg| \frac{X}{n} - p \bigg| > a \bigg) \leq \frac{ {p(1-p)} }{a^2n} 
$$
What inequality about tail probabilities [probabilities of the form $P(Y>t)$] can you use to show this?

If $a\sqrt n\lt\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, you're trying to show:
$$
P \bigg( \bigg| \frac{X}{n} - p \bigg| > a \bigg) \leq \frac{ \sqrt{p(1-p)} }{a\sqrt n} .
$$
This last one is easier to show than it looks.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \simeq p$ and $n$ is large, you can use a normal approximation to get approximate bounds in terms of erf() integrals.